# How to split pyspark dataframe into segments of equal sized rows

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to create a new column that puts rows in my pyspark dataframe into groups based on observed `rank` values. For example, I'd like the first 100,000 ranks to be group 1, the next 100,000 to be group 2, and so on, up to an arbitrary number of ranks (it needs this flexibility as the size of my data, and number of overall ranks is likely to change)

Does anyone know how to achieve this? This is what my intended output looks like

```
--------------------------------------
| id.       |     rank   | segment   | 
--------------------------------------
| 100       |   1        |     1     |  
| 200       |   100,002  |     2     | 
| 300       |   900,007  |     9     |   
--------------------------------------
```

The only help I can find from browsing is for splitting the ranks into some kind of quantile, but I need guarantees that my segments are of size 100,000.

Does anyone have any tips as to how to achieve this outcome?

Some sample code here if it helps

```
import pandas as pd

spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [100,200,300], "rank": [1, 100002, 900007]
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ceil` function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

......
step = 100000
df = df.withColumn('segment', F.expr(f'ceil(rank / {step})'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```